# Do flex box and Bootstrap don't work together on the mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, mobile, flexbox

Applying the CSS rule `display:flex` to a Bootstrap row seems to take the control of Bootstrap column width away from Bootstrap. For example, if I have a column with the class `col-md-9`, it is only as wide on the Android Chrome browser as the width of the text it contains instead of occupying 75% of screen-width according to the Bootstrap grid rules.

What is the underlying cause of this behavior and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply `display:flex` to a `.row`, the width of all its immediate children will no longer be controlled by their `width` property, so the block (Bootstrap) model will no longer work. Mixing Bootstrap 3 layouting classes (based on the block model) with `display:flex` (the flexbox model) is not a good idea.

In the flexbox model, if the `flex-direction` is not set, the first level children of the element with `display: flex` will have their `width` NOT influnenced by the `width` property, but by (not necessarily in this order):

- child `flex-basis`,
- child `flex-grow`
- child `flex-shrink`
- child content actual size (width)
- child's siblings content actual size
- parent `align-items` (if set to `stretch`)
- child `align-self`. (if set to `stretch`)

There are quite a few properties, but it allows fine-grained control over any posible display scenario. Some of them will not apply to `width` if the `flex-direction` is set to `column` on the parent, as they will apply to height in that case.

By the way, Bootstrap 4 comes with flexbox, but it's not out yet.